# spring-data-mongodb entity implementing an interface create wrong collections

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to allow user to choose their own persistence technologies, and to do so developers must write entities that implements given interface.

By default application use spring-data with **mongodb**, the following are extract code from entity:

```
@Document(collection="event_handlers")
@CompoundIndexes({
  @CompoundIndex(name = "handlers_unique_idx", def = "{'eventName': 1, 'className': 1}", unique=true, sparse=true)
})
public class HandlerImpl implements Handler {
  ....
}
```

and its related repository:

```
@Repository
public interface HandlerRepository extends MongoRepository<Handler, String> {
...
}
```

Running integration test, I’ve noticed that application write entity in an unexpected collections, named **handler**, as the entity interface, and not in the expected collection, name **event_handlers**, and besides, the composite key doesn't work because it has been associated with the right collection that remain all time empty.

That's the collection list for my db:

```
> show collections
event_handlers
handler
system.indexes
>
```

How can I use spring-data to use this kind of configuration?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

The collection objects are stored in is determined from the domain type you configure the repository with. Thus you should see this working as expected if you annotate `Handler` with `@Document`.

This works as it works to allow people storing objects of a type hierarchy in a single collection to allow polymorphic queries. If you don't need that, the way to go is a repository interface per concrete domain type.